# Css Content, Attr and Url in the same sentence

Tags: css, url, attr, css-content

I have used the *content attribute* for a long time, and today I wanted to try something new. Instead of using JS to display a image tooltip I wanted to know if it was possible to do it dynamically with CSS.

So I tried:

```
.TableLine:hover:after{
  content: url("../Img/Photo/"attr(id)".jpg"); 
}
```

where `attr(id)` is supposed to return the ID of the picture (alphanumeric) which is also the name of the picture.

It doesn't work at all, it has no effect. I think that the block did not parse because adding a border or background to the block also seems to have no effect.

When I just use the `attr(id)` alone, without the url thing, it works perfectly. It also works when I replace `attr(id)` with the real name of the picture.

After searching a while on the web I haven't found anything relevant so here I am.  Is that a known bug or just my mistake? :)

Comment: I think `attr(id)` just works on strings not on `url`.

Comment: It's the point of my question indeed, to be sure of that ><

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's neither a bug nor a mistake. The currently supported syntax (CSS2.1) for content is:

```
content: normal | none | 
         [ <string> | <uri> | <counter> | attr() |
           open-quote | close-quote | no-open-quote | no-close-quote ]+ | inherit
```

I.e.:

- The literal `normal`, `none` or `inherit`
- Or any number of these ***in succession***:

  - a string - `"hello"`
  - a (constant) URI - `url("image.jpg")`
  - a counter - `counter(section)`
  - an attribute - `attr(id)`
  - `open-quote`, `close-quote`, `no-open-quote`, `no-close-quote`

The [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) don't allow for them to be "nested", they can only follow each other, e.g.:

```
content: "Photo: " url("../Img/Photo.jpg") attr(id);
/* Which is not what you want */
```

The current CSS3 drafts don't allow for it either. Possibly - if it's been discussed - because most use cases would have little to do with presentation and more to do with actual content.

Comment: Ah well, that's explain everything :/
Bit of shame that it's not in discussion, could be awesome to replace JS with css for that kind of thing! 
thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

As of W3C Candidate Recommendation 28 August 2012, there is syntax for specifying the type returned by attr().

It is described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation).

Long story short, the following would work:

```
content: attr(id url);
```

But it still doesn't seem like you would be able to concatenate that with other strings, which is annoying.

Anyhow, this still doesn't seem to be implemented anywhere.

Check [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: attr is basically the red-headed stepchild of the css world. It is capable of so much power, but no one is will to allow it to do so. :(