# jQuery select pseudo element of a given element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, element, pseudo-element

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

If I have an `element`, how do I address its corresponding pseudo element using *jQuery*?

My point is, for example if I have an element in the DOM, how do I access its `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements with *jQuery*?

*P.S. I only have a jQuery pointer to that element.*

Comment: You can't, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There should be a way. I need to add a background to the pseudo element.

Comment: @undefined It may be a duplicate indeed. I'll review it and delete the question myself if it is so.

Comment: I guess that it is really impossible. I looked at the solution of the original question and and I can't adapt it either (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244197/css-content-attr-and-url-in-the-same-sentence).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your looking to create an element that simply doesn't exist. Use jQuery [**`.after()`**](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to create it. (*Likewise, you can use jQuery [**`.before()`**](http://api.jquery.com/before/) too!*)

```html
<div id="element">123</div>
```

```css
#element {
 float: left;
 color: white;
}

.selected {
  background-image:url("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bb7148ce65e69d732186e93116462cb2?s=100&d=identicon&r=PG");
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```js
$('#element').after('<div class="selected"></div>');
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5p3kn/)

[**jsFiddle DEMO with Remove**](http://jsfiddle.net/5p3kn/1/)

Comment: +1 for the solution, but I can't really modify the DOM.

Comment: Please clarify *"I need to add a background"* in your comments. Thanks.