# set Pseudo Elements content url image

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

i am trying to set data-img as image in pseudo element without success, here is what i have tried so far:

the markup:

```
<div data-img="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/cute_baby_in_autumn-wide.jpg">radomPicture</div>
```

the style:

```css
div:before{
    content: url('attr(data-img)');
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

result broken image: http://jsfiddle.net/vfPKb/

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Css Content, Attr and Url in the same sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244197/css-content-attr-and-url-in-the-same-sentence)

Comment: Short answer is that this isn't possible at present. Duplicate link has more in depth explanations.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure this is possible.  You may want to mess around with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), although you may run into the same problem you're having here; I don't believe that you can  send one CSS function a value generated from another (even CSS variables are accessed through a `var` function).  I know it's not as satisfying, but have you considered some quick and easy jQuery?

```
$("div[data-img]").each(function(){$(this).css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).attr("data-img") + ")")});
```

Here's a forked [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUYJr/)

You could do something similar with vanilla Javascript, as well, if you're reluctant to add new libs to your project.

**EDIT:**

If you're able to edit the markup, a far simpler (although maybe not entirely possible) solution may be to just use an inline style:

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/cute_baby_in_autumn-wide.jpg')">radomPicture</div>
```

I can't imagine many scenarios where adding an `img-data` attribute would be significantly easier than adding a `style` attribute, but I guess that depends on how all of this markup is being generated, or if that power is in your hands to begin with.

Comment: i know how to use js  i need a pure css solution

Comment: @ Sandy Gifford yes i did but i want to use the div, before and after separately to save as much data as possible in a single element

Comment: @kougiland You should still be able to use `:before` and `:after`.  Using inline styling shouldn't have any effect on that, it's just more widely supported than `data-` attributes, and doesn't involve stacking functions. **EDIT:** unless you mean using the same background image on the `:before` and `:after` elements as on the `div` itself, that *is* trickier.

Comment: @ Sandy Gifford you are correct i want to use the same background with different css filter

Comment: @kougiland Ahhh, that could be trickier.  There's no real way to do inline pseudos ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)), so that knocks out that solution (for now).  I can't think of any way to achieve this with a simple generic approach.  Can you post more info about what exactly you're trying to achieve?  Maybe we can hack it a bit.

Comment: @kougiland ***ALTHOUGH*** you COULD try experimenting with **[this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515#examples)**.  Looks exciting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37773/discussion-between-kougiland-and-sandy-gifford)

Comment: @kougiland Unfortunately, my work blocks the Stack chat sub domain.