# CSS attr() concatenation with url path

Tags: css, concatenation, attr

How can I concatenate the CSS attr() selector with static text in a url() field?

The HTML I use:

```
<div image='/Require/static.png'></div> //Example 2
<div image='static.png'></div> //Example 3, 4, 5
```

For example:

```
//image attribute contains the image name (and prefix location when needed, see example 2)
div[image]:before {
    background-image: url('/Image/static.png'); //Works
    background-image: url(attr(image)); // Works
    background-image: url('/Image/' attr(image)); //Fails
    background-image: url('/Image/' #attr(image)); //Fails
    background-image: url('/Image/' {attr(image)); //Fails
    }
```

So - if it is possible - How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well with the image tag please.

Comment: The CSS is fairly self-explanatory and shouldn't require HTML to understand.

Comment: Updated, see post

Comment: What browser are you testing in? I wouldn't have expected content: url(attr(image)); to work - it's a syntax error.

Comment: Tested it in Safari and it works. No idea about other browsers. I can also use background-image: url() which is no problem to me. Edited the post to background-image

Comment: Is this SVG or did you just use `<text>` for fun?

Comment: Woops, text should be test. It's a typo. Will change it to div to be more clear anyway

Comment: @TVA van Hesteren: Make sure you're only testing one declaration at a time. It might well be that url(attr(image)) appears to work only because what you're actually seeing is the url('/Image/static.png').

Comment: @BoltClock I use one declaration at a time, this is just to show what options I have tried so far and it's results

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244712/7236046). You can't nest them like that.

Comment: @kevinb. thanks, it indeed is the same as the post you provide, only with a better title to ask the question

Comment: At least read other comments who where in front of you, thanks

Comment: Where do you think the link came from? When you vote to close, SO adds the _"Possible duplicate"_ link for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not possible to create a composite `url()` value out of two or more strings. On top of the legacy `url()` value, which isn't even a proper CSS function (see [Is there a way to interpolate CSS variables with url()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330075/is-there-a-way-to-interpolate-css-variables-with-url/42331003#42331003) — which means you can't even do this with custom properties), the proper CSS function version of `url()` as defined in [css-values-3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#urls) only accepts a single string.<sup>1</sup>

You *can* concatenate multiple strings in a `content` declaration, but [that is a feature of the `content` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#content), not of strings in CSS.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Since `url()` accepts a single string, this does mean that a single `attr()` *can* be used as a URL value, [also new to css-values-3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#attr-notation), as `attr(image url)`... except [browser support is nonexistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers/8769922#8769922).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for you answer and provided documentation!