# Setting a CSS variable to refer to <href> link in a class, then using that variable as a url in content: url()

Tags: css, image, variables, url, hover

I am trying to customize the CSS of a course website in which I cannot use javascript or change the HTML - I can only upload custom CSS files.

I have made it so, in a list of content links to .jpg files, when I hover over the list item, the corresponding image appears underneath. I have got the hover function to work but it requires me to make a new class selector for every file in the list.

The code that shows the image on hover is:

```
.itemlink:hover:after {
  content: url([image url]);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 50%;
}
```

[The image files are linked in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bev87.png).

Is there a way for me to set a variable called "--assetPath" that refers to whatever link is present in the href for the "link-div-head" class in the attached image, so I can place that variable as the content url for the hover effect?

Alternatively, could I set it up so the url is a variable that is set to return the url of an image file if given the file name (ie. the text in the "link-text itemtext" class below the highlighted part in the attached image)?

Basically, is there a way for me to set this up so that the image url is automatically the image that I am hovering on, so I don't have to link each individual file.

I'm fairly new to css so I hope this makes sense. I can provide extra clarification if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: [Try `content:attr('href');`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

Comment: if you have access to html, you could try using css data attributes ( it would look like `content:url(attr(href))` )

Comment: @AjAX. I think so? In the source code of my page, "class=itemLink" appears just below the <href> link I'd like to retrieve.

Comment: Please reload. I saw your image link too late…

Comment: It is actually a mix of @Neil and me I guess. `content:url(attr(href));`

Comment: i just corrected since op could not change html,href should do the job yes :)

Comment: Ok. Now it is — not — a mix anymore @Neil. %)P

Comment: neither the `content: attr('href')` nor `content:url(attr(href))` unfortunately.

Comment: visual studio puts a red underline on the second closed bracket after `(attr(href))`, saying it is expecting a semi-colon

Comment: @AjAX. I changed it to `content: "("attr(href)")";` and it worked, but it displays the image url string instead of the actual image

Comment: [From here try `content:url() attr(href);`. Or something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244197/css-content-attr-and-url-in-the-same-sentence)

Comment: didn't work.. could I set a variable for `content: "(attr(href)")"` then use that variable in another instance of `content:url()` ?

Comment: [It looks like it is in the `specs`. But — not — implemented yet.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968370/2569323)

Comment: well...that's just too bad. thanks for your help

Comment: You will do that for everybody %)P.